# What physics knowledge can be applied to biology of organisms and ecosystems?

Tags: biophysics, theoretical-biology, ecosystem

In the wiki page of [Biophysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biophysics):

> Biophysics spans all scales of biological organization, from the molecular scale **to whole organisms and ecosystems.**

But after searching on the internet; the dominant application of physics in biology that I see is at the molecular scale. In the wiki page [Mathematical biophysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_and_theoretical_biology#Mathematical_biophysics), there is a lot of interesting information, but it is only about mathematical knowledge applied to biophysics, not physics itself.

What, if any, physics knowledge (based on principles and laws of physics) can be applied to biology in the sense of organisms and ecosystems?

Comment: For a non-molecular example, see [biomechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomechanics).

Comment: This question should provide one example: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/how-do-trees-lift-water-higher-than-10-meters/

Comment: Thanks, that's organism scale. What's about ecosystem? @fileunderwater

Comment: You might be interested in reading about biomimetics.

Comment: Brownian motion.. It is used for migrations and dispersal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is really asking for examples, and the list of ways that knowledge of physics can be used in biology could be very long. However, here are a couple of examples:

- **Systems ecology, especially with regard to energy and nutrient flow.**
  This type of ecology can be strongly influenced by physics. For one example see the book [*Theoretical Ecosystem Ecology: Understanding Element Cycles*](http://www.cambridge.org/ar/academic/subjects/life-sciences/ecology-and-conservation/theoretical-ecosystem-ecology-understanding-element-cycles) by Ågren & Bosatta (Ågren was originally a physicist)
- **Physical limitations to growth and transport**
  This can include for instance mechanical contraints on plant growth (see e.g. the book [*Plant Physics*](https://books.google.se/books?id=XeLmGmWl3-IC&pg=PA191#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Nicklas & Spatz), water transport in trees (see e.g. [this BioSE question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/how-do-trees-lift-water-higher-than-10-meters/)) or the biomechanics of movement (see e.g. [Hudson et al (2012)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22723482) on the speed and movement of cheetahs or [Wikipedia: Biomechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomechanics)).
- **Allometric relationships between organisms, e.g. with regard to metabolism**
  To explain these types of relationships knowledge in physics is useful. See e.g. [Kleiber's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleiber%27s_law) for more.
- **MAXENT as a general approach to ecological patterns or to model species distributions**
  This is basically a tool lifted from physics that can be applied to ecological problems. There are many papers to look at, but [Harte & Newman (2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169534714001037) (Harte is another previous physicist) and [Elith et al (2010)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1472-4642.2010.00725.x/abstract) are two good starting points.
- **Dynamical modelling of populations and communities**
  This field use many of the same tools for analysis as physics, e.g. systems of differential equations. One of the pioneers in this field (among many) were [Robert May](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_May,_Baron_May_of_Oxford) (also started with a PhD in physics), and his classical book [*Theoretical Ecology: Principles and Applications*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199209995) is still a good starting point.
- **Energy harnessing and conversion by organisms**
  This can refer both to how organsims convert prey to energy (e.g. conversion efficiencies) and the physics of photosynthesis (which is an interesting intersection between physics and molecular biology). See [Jang et al (2004)](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.218301) and [O'Reilly & Olaya-Castro (2013)](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2014/140109/ncomms4012/full/ncomms4012.html) for examples of the how quantum mechanics can inform us about photosynthesis.

Hopefully this will give you a sense of some different ways that knowledge in physics can be useful for biology.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time writing this wonderful answer :D

Comment: I am currently interested in evolution. Does any of your suggestions have it? Does any field in evolution have physics in there?